# How to subset variable in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I would like to subset a specific variable (not the entire dataset) in gtsummary.

In the following example, how could I subset gear to remove '5' - only show proportion of cars with gear of '3' and '4' ?  I would want to include all patients in mpg however.

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr) 

mtcars %>%
          select(cyl, mpg, gear) %>%
          tbl_summary(
                    by = cyl ### how do i say for gear, filter gear != 5  ???
          )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to build two separate tables with `tbl_summary()` then stack them. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

tbl_full_data <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, mpg) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = cyl) %>%
  # removing Ns from header, since they won't be correct for gear
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")

tbl_gear_subset <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, gear) %>%
  dplyr::filter(gear != 5) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = cyl) 

# stack tables together
list(tbl_full_data, tbl_gear_subset) %>%
  tbl_stack() %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to it'll print on SO
#> i Column headers among stacked tables differ. Headers from the first table are
#> used. Use `quiet = TRUE` to supress this message.
```

| **Characteristic** | **4** | **6** | **8** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | 26.0 (22.8, 30.4) | 19.7 (18.6, 21.0) | 15.2 (14.4, 16.2) |
| gear |  |  |  |
| 3 | 1 (11%) | 2 (33%) | 12 (100%) |
| 4 | 8 (89%) | 4 (67%) | 0 (0%) |

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you